# Storing a PHP Array parsed from a YAML file in Symfony's cache

Tags: caching, symfony, yaml

I have a few YAML files to be parsed from a service.

But at every page hit, those YAML files are parsed and converted to a PHP Array. I understand Symfony keeps the default YAML files cached, so it doesn't parse every yaml file at every page hit.

I was wondering what is the best practice here. Is there a way to have my YAML files parsed only once and stored with Symfony2's cache? If so, could I please be pointed in the right direction?

Comment: I have not much knowledge about it, but what about JmsSerializer (and the JmsSerializerBundle)?

Comment: Not sure if you can somehow utilize Symfony2's caching system, but you can definitely use services from bundles like SonataCacheBundle, to store parsed data.

Comment: I'd be able to serialize my arrays, but I'm not sure how to store them on the cache and load them. Also, SonataCacheBundle doesn't seem to be  quite well documented. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on how you want to do the caching.

- **HTTP caching** really only makes sense when in the web context and when the particular output of the action where you're parsing and adding these files to an array is relatively static. If both of those conditions are met, then that is the best way to go.
- **You can easily use APC** to do your caching. It makes caching the contents of a variable quite simple. Doctrine provides a cache abstraction around APC, or you can use native PHP functions.

in config.yml

```
 services:
        cache:
            class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache
```

then in your controller or service:

```
if ($yamlArray = $this->get('cache')->fetch('foo')) {
    $yamlArray = unserialize($yamlArray);
} else {
    // do the work
    $this->get('cache')->save('foo', serialize($yamlArray));
}
```

- **Make your own caching service and hook it into the Symfony cache commands**

[Details on creating a cache warmer](http://blog.servergrove.com/2012/04/18/how-to-create-a-cache-warmer-in-symfony2/)

[Details on cache_clearer](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/2857)(added but not well documented).

Comment: Those are not templates I'm trying to cache, they're YAML files, not TWIG files. Anyway, the principles of APC caching seem to apply. I'd load the YAML file from the disk, parse it, serialize the array, store it on the APC cache... but how do I check if the serialized version is outdated (or, the YAML configuration has changed and needs to be reloaded/reparsed)? Would I store the file's crc along with the serialized array or something? Won't it be kinda slow on the production environment? I'd love to just run `cache:clear --env=prod` and have it rebuilt on the production environment :(

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the fact that you asked about YAML not Twig, (Mondays make my eyes go cross apparently).

Comment: Re: but how do I check if the serialized version is outdated, you can store the object in the cache along with an `md5_file()` or `crc32()`. For example, `$this->get('cache')->save('foo_' . md5_file($file), $yamlArray)`, then use `$this->get('cache')->fetch('foo_' . md5_file($file))` when fetching.

Comment: Storing a hash as @theunraveler has mentioned is definitely the easiest way. Let the hash algorithm do the work for you.